# ssh config file with multiple ssh versions

Tags: openssh

I really like the "Match" keyword that was added to OpenSSH around version 6.5, and I make heavy use of it in my .ssh/config file.

But that config file is in my NFS-ed home, and so is referenced when I log in to any of several computers in our LAN.

And many of these computers still have ssh versions older than 6.5.

So if I am at one of these computers, and try to ssh (or scp/rsync), I get a complaint that Match is a 'Bad configuration option', and ssh terminates.

I'd much rather ssh proceed without the customizations in my config file, than not work at all.  But I can't seem to find any way to write the config file so that newer versions can make use of newer options, but older version work without them.  If anyone has any bright ideas, please share.

I have managed to work out that I can do "ssh -F /dev/null" with older versions.  I just find it irksome that that is necessary.  Would prefer an "automatic" solution.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Thanks, and my apologies.  Have copied the question to Unix & Linux.